# How to count the number of unique words in sas

Tags: sql, syntax, sas

Could anyone tell me how can I count the number of unique names in variable `name`. It seems I can use `DISTINCT` function, but I dont really know how to use it. Or there might be some other functions to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What's the content of `name`, where does it come from, what is a `unique name` in your application?

Answer (score 2):

Like you said...use `distinct`

```
proc sql;
select count(distinct name) from have;
quit;
```

If you want to retain the number in the macro variable use.. into

Also you can use `proc sort` which may not be as efficient as `proc sql` one though

```
proc sort data=have(keep=name) out=want nodupkey;
by name;
run;
```